# How to retrieve records with a specific condition in mysql?

Tags: mysql

**SQL Statement:**

```
SELECT 
    b.*,
    e.Lastname,
    e.Firstname,
    e.ID_SC,
    e.Program,
    r.BReasonDetails
FROM
    tblbadgetemporaryborrower b
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        e.*, p.Program
    FROM
        tblemployee e
    INNER JOIN tblemployeeprogram p ON p.ID_P = e.ID_P) e ON e.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID
        INNER JOIN
    tblbadgetemporaryborrowerreason r ON r.ID_BR = b.ID_BR
HAVING e.ID_SC = {$_GET['ID_SC']}
ORDER BY b.EmployeeID ASC
```

**Q:** How can I retrieve the employee data with `Lost` reason only and count the occurrences of it.

[image: screenshot]

**Expected output:**

```
100827038 | Larrazabal, Victor Ceasar | 4 (`Lost` count)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is add a WHERE clause to your query

```
SELECT
      b.*,
      e.Lastname,
      e.Firstname,
      e.ID_SC,
      e.Program,
      r.BReasonDetails
      FROM tblbadgetemporaryborrower b
        INNER JOIN (
                     SELECT e.*, p.Program 
                     FROM tblemployee e 
                       INNER JOIN tblemployeeprogram p ON p.ID_P = e.ID_P
                   ) e ON e.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID
      INNER JOIN tblbadgetemporaryborrowerreason r ON r.ID_BR = b.ID_BR

      WHERE r.BReasonDetails = 'Lost'

      HAVING e.ID_SC = {$_GET['ID_SC']} 
      ORDER BY b.EmployeeID ASC
```

Comment: boost my imagination, thank you all your inputs helped me :)

Answer (score 1):

First, in your existing query, you can use `where` rather than `having`.  In addition, you don't want the subquery in the `FROM` clause.  Then you can augment this with another condition:

```
SELECT b.*, e.Lastname, e.Firstname, e.ID_SC, p.Program, r.BReasonDetails
FROM tblbadgetemporaryborrower b INNER JOIN
     tblemployee e
     e.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID JOIN
     tblemployeeprogram p
     ON p.ID_P = e.ID_P INNER JOIN
     tblbadgetemporaryborrowerreason r
     ON r.ID_BR = b.ID_BR
WHERE e.ID_SC = {$_GET['ID_SC']} AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM tblbadgetemporaryborrowerreason r2
              WHERE r2.ID_BR = b.ID_BR AND r2.BReasonDetails = 'Lost'
             )
ORDER BY b.EmployeeID ASC;
```

EDIT:

I thought you wanted all the rows where any was `Lost`.  But I see that you do want an aggregation query:

```
SELECT b.*, e.Lastname, e.Firstname, COUNT(*) as LostCount
FROM tblbadgetemporaryborrower b INNER JOIN
     tblemployee e
     e.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID JOIN
     tblemployeeprogram p
     ON p.ID_P = e.ID_P INNER JOIN
     tblbadgetemporaryborrowerreason r
     ON r.ID_BR = b.ID_BR
WHERE e.ID_SC = {$_GET['ID_SC']} AND r.BReasonDetails = 'Lost'
GROUP BY b.EmployeeId
```

Comment: i'm using `Having` because i will be counting the occurrences of that employee who has `lost` reason can i do that by using where?

Comment: @MattMagallo . . . Yes.  You would normally use `having` only when you are doing an aggregation.  MySQL extends the use as well, but it is not necessary here.